# Create custom token filter with NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

How can I configure Index using NEST with such JSON:

```
"settings":{
  "analysis":{
     "filter":{
        "name_ngrams":{
           "side":"front",
           "max_gram":50,
           "min_gram":2,
           "type":"edgeNGram"
        }
     },
     "analyzer":{            
        "partial_name":{
           "filter":[
              "standard",
              "lowercase",
              "asciifolding",
              "name_ngrams"
           ],
           "type":"custom",
           "tokenizer":"standard"
        }
     }
  }
```

I could create my custom analyzer using `CustomAnalyzer` class, but I could'n find how to create custom filter and register it within my analyzer.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After some searching I've found a solution:

```
var partialName = new CustomAnalyzer
            {
                Filter = new List<string> {"lowercase", "name_ngrams", "standard", "asciifolding"},
                Tokenizer = "standard"
            };

var fullName = new CustomAnalyzer
            {
                Filter = new List<string> {"standard", "lowercase", "asciifolding"},
                Tokenizer = "standard"
            };

client.CreateIndex("indexname", c => c
                .Analysis(descriptor => descriptor
                    .TokenFilters(bases => bases.Add("name_ngrams", new EdgeNGramTokenFilter
                    {
                        MaxGram = 20,
                        MinGram = 2,
                        Side = "front"
                    }))
                    .Analyzers(bases => bases
                        .Add("partial_name", partialName)
                        .Add("full_name", fullName))
                )
                .AddMapping<Company>(m => m
                    .Properties(o => o
                        .String(i => i
                            .Name(x => x.Name)
                            .IndexAnalyzer("partial_name")
                            .SearchAnalyzer("full_name")
                        ))));
```

Comment: what is the difference between index analyzer and search analyzer? why do you need to apply separately?

Comment: I used this article to understand how it works - https://web.archive.org/web/20121021233420/http://euphonious-intuition.com/2012/08/more-complicated-mapping-in-elasticsearch/. It is not available anymore from original url but hopefully it's accesible from web.archive.org

Comment: For anyone looking at this solution using NEST v5.3 ... you want bases.UserDefined rather than bases.Add