# Elasticsearch Nest wildcard query with spaces

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

**Short version:**

I would like to write an elastic search query using Nest to get the full indexed items (`ContentIndexables` in my case as my custom type) which have been indexed. The query is subject to a term query of [some string] + * (i.e. String.StartsWith() where [some string] may or may not contain spaces.

This is different to `CompletionSuggester` since I need to retrieve the full object and not string suggestions.

**What I've tried so far:**

When I query for a text without spaces, the desired output is returned using the code below. If my search term however contains spaces, it doesn't return the expected results.

Here's how I search the fields:

```
var searchResults = _client.Search<ContentIndexable>(
            body =>
            body
                .Index(indexName)
                .Query(
                    query =>
                    query.QueryString(
                        qs => qs.
                                  OnFields(f => f.Title, f => f.TextContent)
                                  .Query(searchTerm + "*"))));
```

And this is a unit test that demonstrates how to reproduce the problem:

```
indexService.IndexUserItemsSync(testGuid, IndexType.submission, new ContentIndexable
        {
            ContentId = Guid.NewGuid(),
            TextContent = "Some description",
            Title = "title"
        });

        indexService.IndexUserItemsSync(testGuid, IndexType.submission, new ContentIndexable
        {
            ContentId = Guid.NewGuid(),
            TextContent = "Some description",
            Title = "title that is long"
        });

        indexService.IndexUserItemsSync(testGuid, IndexType.submission, new ContentIndexable
        {
            ContentId = Guid.NewGuid(),
            TextContent = "Some description",
            Title = "title that likes"
        });

        indexService.IndexUserItemsSync(testGuid, IndexType.submission, new ContentIndexable
        {
            ContentId = Guid.NewGuid(),
            TextContent = "Some description",
            Title = "titlethat"
        });

        var searchResult = indexService.SearchUserItems(testGuid, IndexType.submission, 10, "title");
        Assert.IsNotNull(searchResult);
// this one works
        Assert.AreEqual(4, searchResult.Count());

        var searchResult2 = indexService.SearchUserItems(testGuid, IndexType.submission, 10, "title that");
        Assert.IsNotNull(searchResult2);
// this one does not!!! searchREsult2.Count() evaluates to 0
        Assert.AreEqual(2, searchResult2.Count());
```

As you can see, then I enter "title that", the search comes back empty instead of the two rows I would expect to return.

**Update:**
Some more information: 
I create an index on my type ContentIndexable:

```
public class ContentIndexable : IIndexable
{
    public Guid ContentId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string TextContent { get; set; }
}
```

With this code:

```
_client.CreateIndex(
    indexName,
    descriptor =>
    descriptor.AddMapping<ContentIndexable>(
        m => m.Properties(
            p => p.Completion(s => s
                                       .Name(n => n.Title)
                                       .IndexAnalyzer("standard")
                                       .SearchAnalyzer("standard")
                                       .MaxInputLength(30)
                                       .Payloads()
                                       .PreserveSeparators()
                                       .PreservePositionIncrements())
                     .Completion(s => s.Name(n => n.TextContent)
                                          .IndexAnalyzer("standard")
                                          .SearchAnalyzer("standard")
                                          .MaxInputLength(50)
                                          .Payloads()
                                          .PreserveSeparators()
                                          .PreservePositionIncrements())
                 )));
```

I even tried to escape the whitespace both when I index or when I query with `string.Replace(" ", @"\ ")` but that didn't help.

Changing the search type to wild card didn't help either:

```
var searchResults = _client.Search<ContentIndexable>(
            body =>
            body
                .Index(indexName)
                .Query(
                    query => query.Wildcard(qd => qd.OnField(f => f.Title).Value(searchTerm + "*"))));
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Please note that my `CompletionSuggester` version works with spaces but unfortunately only returns strings. I need to get the **complete item** out in order to fetch the `ContentId`. MY CompletionSuggester implementation:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetAutoCompleteSuggestions(Guid userId, IndexType indexType, int size, string searchTerm)
    {
        string indexName = getIndexName(indexType, userId);

        var result = _client.Search<ContentIndexable>(
            body => body.Index(indexName)
                        .SuggestCompletion("content-suggest" + Guid.NewGuid(),
                                           descriptor => descriptor
                                                             .OnField(t => t.Title)
                                                             .Text(searchTerm)
                                                             .Size(size)));

        if (result.Suggest == null)
        {
            return new List<string>();
        }

        return (from suggest in result.Suggest
                from value in suggest.Value
                from options in value.Options
                select options.Text).Take(size);
    }
```

I know I can take the suggestions, get the full value out (which will result in the two items I'm expecting) and then do a full term match using my first method but that requires 2 separate calls into ElasticSearch (one for complete suggestor and the second one for the term query) but ideally I would like to do it without the round trip if possible.

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Are you trying to implement [completion suggester](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html) or rather your mapping is something like "maybe this will work"?

Comment: Hi @Rob. I have already done completion suggester but that's giving me back a list of strings. That list is correct and contains items with spaces correctly. What I'd like to do, is to do the same with a query that gives me the same result (with spaces) but instead of strings as suggestions, I need to get the entire indexed object out (ContentIndexable in my case). I am a complete newbie in ElasticSearch as you may have guessed so any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is example how you can deal with your problem for `Title` field.

Change your mapping to something like(or use [MultiField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23650618/proper-way-to-do-multi-field-with-nest), but I couldn't find option to map field as string and completion in the same time):

```
client.CreateIndex(indexName, i => i
    .AddMapping<ContentIndexable>(m => m
        .Properties(
            ps => ps
                .Completion(c => c.Name("title.completion")
                    .IndexAnalyzer("standard")
                    .SearchAnalyzer("standard")
                    .MaxInputLength(30)
                    .Payloads()
                    .PreserveSeparators()
                    .PreservePositionIncrements())
                .String(s => s.Name(x => x.Title).CopyTo("title.completion")))));
```

Change your `SuggestCompletion` to

```
var result = client.Search<ContentIndexable>(body => body
    .Index(indexName)
    .SuggestCompletion("content-suggest" + Guid.NewGuid(),
        descriptor => descriptor
            .OnField(t => t.Title.Suffix("completion"))
            .Text("title")
            .Size(10)));
```

and `QueryString` to

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<ContentIndexable>(body => body
    .Index(indexName)
    .Query(query => query
        .QueryString(
            qs => qs
                .OnFields(f => f.Title.Suffix("completion"))
                .Query("title tha" + "*")
                .MinimumShouldMatchPercentage(100))));
```

Problem with this solution is fact that we are storing data twice for `Title` field. This is why I mentioned earlier that would be great to use [MultiField](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html) but I wasn't able to do this with the `NEST`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much Rob. This worked with the exception that if my query string contained non alpha numeric characters, it would return nothing. Before I query, I remove those characters now and it works perfectly.