# Favor exact matches over ngram matches in ElasticSearch when mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have partial matching of words working with ngrams.  How can I modify the mapping to always favor exact matches over ngram tokens?  I do not want to modify the query.  One search box will search multiple types, each with their own fields.

For example, lets say I'm searching job titles, one person has a title of "field engineer", the other a title of "engine technician".  If a user searches for "engine", I'd want ES to return the latter as more relevant.

I'm using this mapping almost verbatim: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19874785/978622
-Exception: I'm using an ngram with min of 3 and max of 11 instead of edge ngram

Is it possible to apply a boost/function score to an analyzer? If so I'll apply both the "full_name" and "partial_name" analyzers to my index as well and boost the first.

Edit: I'm using ElasticSearch 1.1.1 and Nest 1.0.0 beta

Comment: Are you restricted to 1 result per query? Without knowing ES, I'd suggest that you leave it, return bot and let the user select.

Comment: No, it returns a list as large as I specify.  But think on a bigger scale. My index has 20000 items.  The example I gave will happen on a much larger scale. I can't just let the user choose.

Comment: You can present the user with a number of choices, e.g. 10 (still not worrying about ordering, because users can select anyway). If the desired result is not listed, user narrows. This is how it works...

Comment: @MarcellFülöp This misses the point of the question. Rather than ignore the problem, I'd like to fix it. Leaving it to users is not a fix.

Comment: That's why I'm not giving an answer just trying to suggest that perhaps you are unnecessarily overcomplicating. I understand the problem and what you want, but I don't think it is a problem or that it's worth the effort to bother with the ordering of those few results unless there is a really good reason which you haven't come up with yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't believe there is anyway to apply boosting to an analyzer as you're suggesting.

One thing you can try, is to use the [multi field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#_multi_fields_3) type in your mapping.  You could then apply your `partial_name` analyzer to one version of the field, and your `full_name` analyzer to the other version.

With this mapping, you could query both fields differently, but combined (perhaps in a bool query), and apply a boost to the query that is being conducted on the `full_name` analyzed field.

Comment: I believe this is what you're saying. I did use multifield. On the index side of things each field had 2 fields. One for a full match analyzer one that had an "ngram" suffix with an ngram analyzer. On the query side I used a simplequerystring using "OnFieldsWithBoost" Any full fields I searched had a .1 higher boost than any ngram fields searched.

Comment: Yup, that's essentially what I was saying.  I'm assuming it worked out?

Comment: It took a little experimenting to get the weights correct without overweighting any specific field, but yes it worked perfect.

Comment: The link is dead.  [Try this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/_multi_fields.html#_multi_fields)

Comment: what is the analyzer that I should use for exact matching?