# Elasticsearch prefer exact match over partial matches when doing typeahead searches

Tags: elasticsearch

I have configured es to do autocomplete and I can also get exact match preferred over suggestions.

For example if someone type London, the api returns London first then Londonderry. But if someone type Londo then es returns Londonderry first then London. Surely, London is a closer match than Londonderry.

Same thing happens with "New York" and York. "New York" is preferred over York when I search for York.

I am using the solution provided here.
[Favor exact matches over nGram in elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26130699/favor-exact-matches-over-ngram-in-elasticsearch)

Comment: How do you differentiate between "New York" and "Duke of York" in your searches? Which is a closer match in your opinion?

Comment: Could be any in this case.

Comment: :-) the idea of my question was to find out from you a deterministic way (a rule or set of rules) by which you define which entry should Elasticsearch choose? For example, choose by relevancy, choose by size, choose by frequency etc...

Comment: Sorry new to ES, I thought it was by relevancy by default. Yes, what you are suggesting is exactly what I need to do but don't know how.

Comment: You can read more about relevancy in ES here: http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/relevance-intro.html. It not just depend on length, it also depend on term freq., doc freq. For typeahead/completion you can also use `Completion Suggester` feature: http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-suggesters-completion.html

Answer (score 1):

This code was helpfull for me:

```
"query": {
    "match": {
         "message": {
              "query": inputQuery,
              "fuzziness": 3,
              "prefix_length": 2
         }
     }
 }
```

first of all you should use `fuzziness` - [ES documentation](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html)

I hope it will help you also.